# searchbar using react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to do a drop-down search bar using react select and it keeps failing
any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

the json data is fine when I'm just using useEffect to create a dropdown

```js
import React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'; 

 async function FetchPokemonNames() {
  const [pokemonNames, setPokemonNames] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    pokemonNames();

async function pokemonNames() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3001/pokemonNames"
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setPokemonNames(data);
  }
  
}, []);


console.log(pokemonNames)
return  pokemonNames;
}


const options = await FetchPokemonNames();

export default function SearchBar() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        defaultValue={selectedOption}
        onChange={setSelectedOption}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the json from 3001 looks like that

```js
[
{
"value": "bulbasaur",
"label": "bulbasaur"
},
{
"value": "ivysaur",
"label": "ivysaur"
},
{
"value": "venusaur",
"label": "venusaur"
},
{
"value": "charmander",
"label": "charmander"
}
]
```

the console gives the following errors

```js
1.Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
react

2.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at FetchPokemonNames (searchBar.js:7:1)
    at ./src/components/searchBar.js (searchBar.js:29:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:15:79)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

I'm really struggling understanding whats the problem
tnx

Comment: What is wrong? What is happening? Do you get any errors?

Comment: the page itself shows a search bar that disappears on click
the console shows some errors , ill update the post to show the errors